# How can I change decimal place in HSPICE?

Tags: hspice

Currently, the numbers in xxx.mt0 file are with 3 decimal place (example: 1.331e-07). I was wondering if I can set a flag in .sp file to increase the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The .OPTION INGOLD controls the format of numbers in printouts.
- The .OPTION NUMDGT=x controls the listing printout accuracy.
- The .OPTION MEASDGT=x controls the measure file printout accuracy.

In your case, you should change in .OPTIONS.

Comment: It worked. Just to add to this information: range is 0 to 10, numdgt=4
is the default.

Comment: Bravo.. and I just looked up an answer and have zero experience on Hspice